# Different .NET build result when run in Bamboo

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, bamboo

I am building a .net 4.5.2 application using Atlassian Bamboo. The build has been operating fine with dependencies on `Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data` for several weeks.

On a recent feature branch I have added a dependency on `Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.dll` version 2015.3.1104.45. Now the build is failing.

> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView,
>   Version=2015.3.1104.45, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
>   make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation errors. 24-Dec-2015 08:11:23
>
> error MC3074: The tag 'RadGridView' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation'. Line 55 Position
>   18.

As is traditional when builds fail, I followed these triage steps:

1. Checkout the offending commit and test build on my workstation
2. If it *"works on my machine™*", log in to the build server and test build using the working directory that failed

I build both steps in the visual studio 2015 IDE. In this instance - both builds succeed. Frustrating! So I take to the command line and build the solution using the command line executed by Bamboo:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com"  "SolutionNameRedacted.sln" /rebuild Release
```

This also succeeds!

I noticed the following line in the bamboo log:

> 24-Dec-2015 08:10:23
>     C:\Atlassian\Data\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\CS-CC13-JOB1>call
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
>   amd64  24-Dec-2015 08:10:23   '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command,

This batch file is used to specify the compiler toolset. Is it a problem that it is not found? I always assumed compiler preferences were expressed by the project files. I have checked the `Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0` directory and vcvarsall.bat does not exist anywhere.

The only significant change to the csproj file since it last built is the addition of this line:

```
<Reference Include="Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView, Version=2015.3.1104.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5803cfa389c90ce7, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

I am at a bit of a loss as it is causing delivery to slip massively.

My current theory is that it is a user account issue and bamboo does not have access the to Telerik assembly it needs. My next steps are too:

1. References the assembly using `clr-namespace` in the xaml file that is breaking
2. Test the build on a user account with elevated permissions (sadly i don't have that kind of access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Telerik do not install their binaries to the GAC. Visual Studio require a `<hintpath>` entry in the csproj file to help discovery. This path should be to you install directory.

Does this sound like a faff? It is abd I'm not terribly impressed. Thankfully the Telerik VS Extension will add the reference and hintpath for you. My recommendation is to always use this wizard.

The downside - all of your developers need the Telerik library installed in the same folder. I'm pretty sure you can manually register binaries with the GAC to skirt this.